# OwnCloud nginx config

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04, owncloud

I'm trying to configure nginx for my homeserver needs, and I experience some troubles with it.

Here's config I use:

```
upstream php-handler {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.nginx-debian.html ;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        # With php7.0-cgi alone:
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php7.0-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}



server {
    listen 80;
    server_name owncloud.my.server.name.ru;

    #ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/nginx/.crt;
    #ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/nginx/.key;

    # Add headers to serve security related headers
    # Before enabling Strict-Transport-Security headers please read into this topic first.
    #add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
    add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
    add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;

    # Path to the root of your installation
    root /var/www/html/owncloud/;

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    # The following 2 rules are only needed for the user_webfinger app.
    # Uncomment it if you're planning to use this app.
    #rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta last;
    #rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json last;

    location = /.well-known/carddav {
        return 301 $scheme://$host/remote.php/dav;
    }
    location = /.well-known/caldav {
        return 301 $scheme://$host/remote.php/dav;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge { }

    # set max upload size
    client_max_body_size 512M;
    fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

    # Disable gzip to avoid the removal of the ETag header
    gzip off;

    # Uncomment if your server is build with the ngx_pagespeed module
    # This module is currently not supported.
    #pagespeed off;

    error_page 403 /core/templates/403.php;
    error_page 404 /core/templates/404.php;

    location / {
        rewrite ^ /index.php$uri;
    }

    location ~ ^/(?:build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates|data)/ {
        return 404;
    }
    location ~ ^/(?:\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console) {
        return 404;
    }

    location ~ ^/(?:index|remote|public|cron|core/ajax/update|status|ocs/v[12]|updater/.+|ocs-provider/.+|core/templates/40[34])\.php(?:$|/) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        #fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        fastcgi_param modHeadersAvailable true; #Avoid sending the security headers twice
        fastcgi_param front_controller_active true;
        fastcgi_pass php-handler;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_request_buffering off; #Available since nginx 1.7.11
    }

    location ~ ^/(?:updater|ocs-provider)(?:$|/) {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        index index.php;
    }

    # Adding the cache control header for js and css files
    # Make sure it is BELOW the PHP block
    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php$uri$is_args$args;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=7200";
        # Add headers to serve security related headers (It is intended to have those duplicated to the ones above)
        # Before enabling Strict-Transport-Security headers please read into this topic first.
        #add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
        add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
        add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;
        # Optional: Don't log access to assets
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:svg|gif|png|html|ttf|woff|ico|jpg|jpeg)$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php$uri$is_args$args;
        # Optional: Don't log access to other assets
        access_log off;
    }
}
```

When I enter owncloud.my.domain.ru - I get ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error in the browser.

When I use my.domain.ru - I get redirected to nginx root (var/www/html/index.php) correctly.

There's also another issue. During my attempt, I trued to use another domain: myseconddomain.tech, which I setup as owncloud.myseconddomain.tech. During that attempt I added redirection from http to https. And now, even though I removed it from config completely, any time I use owncloud.myseconddomain.tech it redirects me to https://my.domain.ru, which is not served by the server at all (and it gets me ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED ofcourse).

I tried restarting nginx, -s reload, rebooting the server, nothing helps.

Please, help me, what am I doing wrong here?
I can provide any additional information required.
Thanks.

---

### Update:

Indeed, the second issue was caused either by DNS not being updated by the time I was testing it on the server, or by the browser cache.

I tried it again, and it gave me 502 Bad Gateway error. Following advice from googling I changed this bit in `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` file

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
;was listen = /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock
```

(I guess I could change the `default` file instead to use `...fpm.sock`.. does this make any difference for the following issue?)

Now I finally got to the "Add domain as trusted" page of OwnCloud. But when I click on "Add" button, it redirects me to lan ip `http://192.168.1.17/settings/admin?trustDomain=owncloud.mydomain.tech` and throws:

```
404 Not Found

nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
```

Where might be the problem now?

Comment: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED is a DNS issue and not related to your server. The other problem may be related to the browser cache.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction, it was  indeed just a DNS issue. But there's another issue now, I updated the post